# Backup/restore sqlite file for Core data with Dropbox

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, backup, dropbox

I'd like to implement a backup and restore feature in a sql-backed Core Data app. I can successfully backup and restore .sqlite file via dropbox, but I have one question about this approach.

If, in the future, my data model changed there are 2 possibles case that will happen.

1. User backup in newer version and restore it in the older version of my app. From my understanding that will cause some schema error.
2. User backup in older version and restore it in the newer one. I think this one will work just fine because it should migrate as normal case.

If this assumption are right, what should I do to handle the problem that may occur from the first case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When I make backup I create it as zip file containing plist file with stored version of backup in it. When I do restore I check that version and if backup is newer than current version I deny restore. It doesn't make sense to restore backup in older app version.
2. As long as You have necessary models it will work properly.

Comment: Yes, I know it doesn't make sense to restore backup in older app, but I can't predict users behavior, so better safe than sorry :)

Comment: Could you share steps to swap sql file after restore, I just got some `CoreData could not fulfill a fault` error.

Comment: You have to close all mom's, persistent stores and moc's before replacing db file. Otherwise you got this error. Sometimes, in my app unfortunately same thing happens, so finally in one of updates I've decided to force app exit after restore - this breakes Apple rules, but it's working. When I have more time I'll have to fix that bug :)